# IntelliJ keeps displaying annoying message: Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:56568): java.net.BindException "Address already in use"

Tags: intellij-idea

I am writing a simple JAR application in IntelliJ. When I debug it for the first time, it works without any problem. But when I try to debug a second time, I get this annoying message:

```
Unable to open debugger port (127.0.0.1:56568): java.net.BindException "Address already in use"
```

If I wait for sometime and then try again, it works. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Typically this happens because you haven't closed your previous debugging/run instance before starting the next one.  The debugger will use a TCP port that you specify, and ports are exclusive: you cannot have two processes that bind to the same port.

In IDEA 14+, you can mark a Run Configuration as "Single instance only".  This will ensure that the previous process is stopped if you (accidentally) run it while the previous instance was still running.

Comment: thanks. I'll try it but this happens when the process has finished and exited.

Comment: You are not alone. I observe the same behavior more often than not

Comment: @morpheus did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows:

1. Open CMD
2. Type

   > netstat -a -o -n
3. Search on the result list on column Local Address the port 56568
4. Look to the right on column PID for its process ID, for example: 1234
5. Type

   > taskkill /F /PID 1234